# How to find the MLE for $P(X>a)$ for $n$ iid normal random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

I am given that $X_i \stackrel {iid}\sim N(\theta,\sigma^2)$ for $i=1,\cdots,n$, with known $\sigma$ and given $a$. Where $p=\mathbb P(X_1>a)$, I am asked to find the MLE of $p$.

So far, I have tried to put the joint likelihood of the $X_i$ in terms containing $p$. I have not succeeded in doing this. I know that 
$$L(\mathbf{\vec{X}})=(2\pi\sigma^2)^{-n/2}\exp\left\{-\frac1{2\sigma^2} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\theta)^2\right\}$$
and that $p=1-\Phi(\frac{a-\theta}\sigma)$, with $\Phi$ the cdf of $N(0,1)$. But I can't find a way to put $p$ into the expression for $L(\mathbf{\vec{X}})$.

**Edit:** after reading [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/268567/mle-estimator-of-px-leq-c-for-x-normal-theta-1/268570#268570) question on Cross Validated, I have a possible answer, which I will put below. Comments would be appreciated.

Comment: You should use invariance of the MLE: if your parameter is $\theta$ and the mle is $\hat{\theta}$ then the MLE of $g(\theta)$ is $g(\hat{\theta})$. So, you just need to find the MLE of $\theta, \sigma^2$ and plug them into the definition of $P(X_1 > a)$.

Comment: Thanks; the link I found on Cross Validated suggests that strategy as well.

Comment: "But I can't find a way to put $p$ into the expression for $L(\mathbf{\vec{X}})$." If you must, use $$\theta=a-\sigma\Phi^{-1}(1-p)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/268567/mle-estimator-of-px-leq-c-for-x-normal-theta-1/268570#268570) related question on Cross Validated, I used the following reasoning. (Any comments as to the validity of this reasoning would be appreciated.)

Recall that the MLE of $\theta$ is $\bar X$. Notice $p=\mathbb P(\frac {X-\theta}\sigma>\frac{a-\theta}\sigma)=1-\Phi(\frac{a-\theta}\sigma)$. Thus, by the invariance property of MLEs, where $\delta$ is the MLE of $p$ we have
$$\delta=1-\Phi\left(\frac{a-\bar X}\sigma\right).$$